# My hamburger menu on mobile doesn't open on a few pages (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm experiencing a few issues. I'm using a wordpress theme called listable. Everything has been working smoothly for a few months so I don't think its a theme issue.

My hamburger menu works on a few pages such as the homepage and individual listing page.

Example (works)
Homepage - https://osdoro.com.sg
Listing page - https://osdoro.com.sg/offices/8-person-serviced-office-12-marina-view-18961-singapore/

Example (doesn't work)
Search page - https://osdoro.com.sg/office-coworking/marina-bay/
Office building page - https://osdoro.com.sg/office-buildings/6-raffles-boulevard-singapore/

I've checked the console log and I'm guessing its something to do with this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

But I'm left figuring out why it only works for a few pages?

Comment: This is working for me in chrome on the suggested pages. Maybe clear your cache?

Comment: It's not working for me in chrome.
Maybe the problem in this console error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: elementorModules is not defined."

Does elementor editor work for these pages?